# Python -> PyQT 5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qss

Есть такие вопросы, могу ли я в *PyQT5* имея картинку установить ее на главный фон и на этой картинке создать экран, в котором при нажатии определенных клавиш (например стрелок) передвигать графические элементы.

А также, чтобы этот экран включался только при нажатии определенной клавиши с другого компьютера, то есть привязать это всё по сети. Если да, то с помощью какого виджета можно реализовать данный экран?

Comment: пожалуйста. задайте только один вопрос. Приведите пример кода, который у вас есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечаю на первый ваш вопрос: "Как в PyQT5 имея картинку установить ее на главный фон?".

Как вариант, используйте таблицу стилей.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QMainWindow, QApplication


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

# vvvvvvvv
StyleSheet = """
QMainWindow{
    border-image: url(opencv_color.jpg) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
}
"""


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)                                   # +++
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle("Title MainWindow")
    w.resize(702, 343)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @ZheD1s если вас интересуют другие ответы на следующие вопросы - задайте новый вопрос и не забываете прикреплять ваш код.